# JMeter, JUnit and Spring Java configuration

Tags: spring, junit, jmeter, autowired

Is it possible to run JMeter with the JUnit plugin/sampler and Spring Java configuration?  When I try to do this, the Spring autowired beans are not being created and although the test case runs, because the beans have not been created, I get null pointer exceptions.

I am using the Spring annotation
`@SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` and `@ContextConfiguration` to configure the JUnit test (which works). The goal is to be able to write JUnit test cases that can be measured for performance using JMeter.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, running JMeter with JUnit and Spring is a problem.
JMeter does not use standard JUnit runner; its specified at
[User manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request), point 7. There are subtle differences between standard JUnit test runners and JMeter's implementation. Because of this, `@SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` is becomes ignored. Workaround is to load beans as normal i.e using `ApplicationContext.getBean()`.